# Two stack views with same settings but different results

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint, uistackview

I have two custom tableView cells; one designed in a left-right layout with an image on the left and a multiline label on the right. The other has the exact same thing, but with the label on the left and the image on the right. The image and label are contained in a stack view in both cases, and the settings are identical: `Axis = Horizontal, Alignment = Center, Distribution = Fill Proportionally, Spacing = 10`.
Both labels have the same layout constraints; top/bottom pinned (for resizing the cell) and `width >= 100`.

In the case where the label is on the left, its width gets set to zero at runtime, and the text doesn't appear. Is there any reason I'm not aware of why the two orders of objects would behave differently.

UPDATE: Here's what I have in the tableViewController's delegate methods:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "Help: The Basics"
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

// MARK: - Table view data source
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let item = items[indexPath.row]
    var cell: HelpTableViewCell? = nil
    switch item.layoutType {
    case .left:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HelpDefaultCell") as! HelpDefaultTableViewCell
    case .right:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HelpAlternateCell") as! HelpAlternateTableViewcell
    case .vertical:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HelpVerticalCell") as! HelpVerticalTableViewcell
    }
    cell!.uiImage.image = item.image
    if item.imageIsHidden {
        cell!.uiImage.isHidden = true
    }
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        // this is the overview text -- no image!
        let text = item.helpString
        let formattedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
        formattedString
            .bold(text, size: 19.0)
        cell!.helpTextLabel.attributedText = formattedString
    } else {
        cell!.helpTextLabel.text = item.helpString
    }
    return cell as! UITableViewCell
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return items.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    (view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView).backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
}
```

[image]
[image]

I do (obviously enough) get a conflict:

```
2018-11-05 09:32:01.284852-0800 xxx[7760:2416718] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2825fcf50 UILabel:0x14ddca540'Touch the xxx graphic t...'.width >= 100   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2825fce10 'fittingSizeHTarget' UILabel:0x14ddca540'Touch the xxx graphic t...'.width == 0   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2825fcf50 UILabel:0x14ddca540'Touch the xxx graphic t...'.width >= 100   (active)>
```

I'm confused by this, because I don't have any `.width == 0` constraints. These must be added automatically, I suppose? (Despite that error, this particular cell renders correctly.)

UPDATE: I can get it to layout the way I want, and to avoid layout errors, by choosing `Equal Centering`, rather than `Fill Proportionally`. Who knows...

Comment: **Both labels have the same layout constraints**, have you given constraints to stackView or labels ?

Comment: The stack views are constrained the same way: leading/trailing = 15, top/bottom = 0. I should add, I suppose, that the tableViewCells are both coming from xib files.

Comment: Can you please share the sample code for the tableView delegate methods ?

Comment: In the view debugger I can see that the image is taking the complete width of the cell. That's why I was wondering about the stack view behaviour. What's very strange to me is that the "default" layout shows the text correctly.

Comment: Remove the constraints for HelpText label and make its number of lines to be 0 or some value. Try again

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried removing all my arrangedView width constraints with no change. The number of lines is 0, and the vertical space resizes as expected. Strangely, it works if I choose `Equal Centering`.... Perhaps it's because the text is set after creating the cell? That kinda makes no sense to me, but maybe... (But actually, `Equal Centering` brings up a conflict in IB regarding the image's x position... what a fiasco.)